# Unable to schedule falcon process - Could not perform authorization operation, java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, falcon, apache-falcon

​Hi,
I am trying to schedule a falcon process using falcon CLI and falcon service user on a Kerberised cluster. I am getting the following error message:

```
ERROR: Bad Request;default/org.apache.falcon.FalconWebException::org.apache.falcon.FalconException: Entity schedule failed for process: testHiveProc
```

Falcon app logs shows following:

```
used by: org.apache.falcon.FalconException: E0501 : E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams; Host Details :
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause:
Oozie was running out of processes due to more number of scheduled jobs.

Short term solution:
Restart Oozie server

Long term solution:
-   Increase ulimit
-   Limit the number of scheduled jobs in Oozie